# lowprofileimageloader in win 8 c#

Tags: windows-8

I am developing a windows 8 xaml application it consumes large number of data from web services include images.  I want to cache the data and images locally so once the internet connection goes out the user is still able to use the application.  Currently i am saving the image at the image_opened event and it produces lot of issues like access denied like that.  Is there any better way to load and cache the image in windows 8 like low profile image loader in windows phone 7?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JetImageLoader](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader), I created it for application, where we need to load, cache and show big amount of logos, icons and so on.

It can be used as binding converter, so *you should not even change your code! Just update your XAMLs!*

Please, check out [samples in repository](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader), you'll love it ;)

**Features:**

- Caching on disk
- Caching in memory
- Fully asynchronous
- Available as binding converter or programmatically from your code
- Fully open source, fork and improve it!

Here is the example:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource MyAppJetImageLoaderConverter}}"/>
```

P.S. I am sorry, that I copying my answer from another questions, but image caching on windows phone is huge problem and I want to share my solution, so everybody can use it and improve for developers community